# How to get a user name of the interactive login session that a process is running in?

Tags: swift, macos, root, bsd

From my macOS GUI app (written in Swift and C) how do I find out the interactive user name for the login session where my process is running?

I know that I can use `getuid()` and `geteiud()` to get the user ID that the process is running under, but that doesn't work if the GUI app is elevated to root with the call to [`AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1540038-authorizationexecutewithprivileg). In that case I still get the root user, when I need the name of the interactive user whose desktop the app is running in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS has a special function for that: [SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1517123-scdynamicstorecopyconsoleuser?language=objc). Here's the [example](https://dennisbabkin.com/blog/?t=macos-programming-critical-sections-reader-writer-locks-login-sessions-root-strings#this_login_session) how you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getlogin/getlogin_r` functions from `unistd.h` to get the name of the user logged in on the controlling terminal of the process.

See [getlogin manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getlogin).

Comment: Thanks, but that still gives me "root".